# Generics for Arrays in TypeScript 3.0

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

So I see that 3.0 comes with generic typings for rest parameters so you can do something like this:

```
static identity<T extends any[]>(...values: T): T;
```

Is it possible to get something similar for array arguments, or is there currently something working that I'm unaware of? For example if you look at the [es6-promise declarations](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/blob/master/es6-promise.d.ts)

```
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>, T6 | Thenable<T6>, T7 | Thenable<T7>, T8 | Thenable<T8>, T9 | Thenable<T9>, T10 | Thenable<T10>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>, T6 | Thenable<T6>, T7 | Thenable<T7>, T8 | Thenable<T8>, T9 | Thenable<T9>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>, T6 | Thenable<T6>, T7 | Thenable<T7>, T8 | Thenable<T8>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>, T6 | Thenable<T6>, T7 | Thenable<T7>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>, T6 | Thenable<T6>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>, T5 | Thenable<T5>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>, T4 | Thenable <T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
static all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>, T3 | Thenable<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
static all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>, T2 | Thenable<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
static all<T1>(values: [T1 | Thenable<T1>]): Promise<[T1]>;
static all<TAll>(values: Array<TAll | Thenable<TAll>>): Promise<TAll[]>;
```

The spec for `Promise.all` is that it takes in an iterable rather than rest parameters. It would be truly nice to not have to write out all of those typings, but from my tertiary knowledge of TypeScript 3.0 it is not yet possible. Am I correct?

Comment: in `static identity<T extends any[]>(...values: T): T;` `T` will be a tuple type based on input arguments. I have tried to map a tuple type (applying some transformation to each item in the tuple type) but this does not seem to currently be well supported.

Comment: `Promise.all` presents an additional problem because you can pass in an array of `T | PromiseLike<T>` and all the promises will be resolved. However, it doesn't seem that TS 3.0 solves the main problem of array params as generic tuples.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir if you weren't aware, [tuple mapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) should be fully supported in TS 3.1.  Not that this solves this question completely, since it asks about inferring a tuple for an array-like input without the rest parameter.

Comment: @jcalz wow, 10x for the info, that is great news. I'm a bit surprised it's not on the road map, this seems like a pretty important improvement!

Comment: FYI I updated my answer to show how to get array literals inferred as tuples without the caller having to do anything.

Comment: YES, this is huge!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE 2019-10-06: YES, THIS IS POSSIBLE AS OF TS3.1.

See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179) and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) for the trick of including a tuple type in the context of what you're trying to infer.  Like this:

```
declare function all<T extends any[] | []>( // note | [] here
  values: T
): Promise<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Thenable<infer R> ? R : T[K] }>;
```

Note how the type `any[] | []` isn't much different from `any[]` (the type `[]` is assignable to `any[]`, so `any[] | []` is really the same set of types as `any[]`), but having the empty tuple `[]` mentioned gives the compiler a hint that you'd like `T` to be inferred as a tuple if possible.  AND IT WORKS:

```
declare const thenableString: Thenable<string>;
const a = all(["hey", thenableString, 123]); // Promise<[string, string, number]>;
```

See [link to code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=83#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIjgIwDYQA8ASgHzIDeAUMsmJiIQKqkAUA9iAGICueMwPAQAmAfgBcyVgDc4eHhEnEAlMgC85JsgA+aBrgLNSAGmSdiEAFYQEkMZNbQo7KJLggAnqo3ItujFgGRCzKkgHY+MGkANw0dAxGHNx8AkIQ9lKy8orIKuqaOnqBkUam5lY2dhJSTi5unt7k0uzAwqFFEYYssQC+VFTCNnhwUCgwPCC2wJzIcniEqMgQAB6QIMIAzrOeANoAuoX7bHFZChthVO0ACs4AtsAbRBTIOwDSyKDIANYQHuwwaD2YTeBxWa02HSChFAMGguXIolyyGBrwOPRi-UGCGGo2QCE4GzA8WKBAAymAoKAAOZhfQlQmUkBUjH4kCE2bqWZCVg7ABEmA8vNM9BJEHJjKppgAjAAmADMe2U0WQAHoVcgbux7o9CDsGdTTPqmaYQDxbjhoHsYkA).

---

OLD ANSWER BELOW:

I think TypeScript 3.1 will introduce [tuple mapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063), which will help for part of this.  But unfortunately I don't know of a way to convince an array-like function parameter to be inferred as a tuple without using a rest parameter.  The closest I can get right now to what you want (using `typescript@next` to get mapped tuples) is:

```
declare function all<T extends any[]>(
  values: T
): Promise<{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Thenable<infer R> ? R : T[K]}>;
function tuple<T extends any[]>(...args: T) { return args};
declare const thenableString: Thenable<string>;
const a = all(tuple("hey",thenableString,123)); // Promise<[string, string, number]>;
```

I'll think about this more and edit the answer if I find a better solution.

---

Update: doesn't look possible for now.  Values just don't get inferred as tuples.  This is a [long-standing issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3369) which was (originally) considered to be intentional behavior...  Now that tuples are getting more powerful, there's [another more recent GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25516) asking about this, with a specific reference to how it's needed for `Promise.all` in the comments.  If you care about it you might want to go to that issue and give it a  or participate in the discussion.

Hope that is helpful.  Good luck.